# Set local storage item to browser where the key has a backslash

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser

I want to set local storage item to browser where the key has a backslash. For example the key would look like

CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.\admin.idToken

I used the below query with "double backslashes \\" but still it produces a garbage value in LocalStorage in browser. 
If we console.log(CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.\\admin.idToken), it prints the expected output in console,but in browser, the \ is not recognized.

browser.executeScript('localStorage.setItem("CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.
\\admin","token")');

Comment: Calling `localStorage.setItem("CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.\\admin.idToken", 42)` works just fine for me. I see value `42` assigned to key `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.\admin.idToken` in my app's local storage.

Comment: I suspect the `executeScript(...)` function may be tampering with the string you're passing in. Try to experiment via `browser.executeScript(console.log('\\'))` and `browser.executeScript(console.log('\\\\'))` to see what will be logged.